Remove Music, Pictures and Videos from This PC in the Navigation Pane
I followed this post, remove 3d objects and was able to get rid of the folders that I don't want like Music, Pictures and Videos. But under the This PC in the Navigation Pane, I am able to see those.
Is there a group policy setting or any registry setting that I can enable to get rid of those?
Here is what the explorer looks like:

EDIT:
All answers are valid to apply this setting to the whole computer. After doing some research I saw, under this path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace(some value)" in the registry you have to delete the respective keys to hide the folders from This PC. Something like this.
But I don't want to apply this setting to the whole machine. I have 2 accounts. One admin and one standard. I logged in to the Admin, I am adding a standard account. I click on HKEY_USERS -> File -> Load Hive -> Added NTUSER.dat. But problem is, I can't find MyComputer under the Explorer here. The path is, "Computer\HKEY_USERS\IT ADMIN\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Can't find MyComputer Node"
But I don't understand how is it showing the Music, Videos and Pictures in the Navigation Pane.

I updated my question. Is there a way to remove those?

Sorry about that changed it.

The post just gives me a registry file and I double click on it. Is there a way to know what is the specific registry setting. Problem is, I am doing it per user basis and don't want to affect all users

Look at the .reg file. It is easily understood, and can be opened in any text editor. Never blindly run a .reg file you do not understand.

Sure I am trying.

If you don't understand what a reg file is doing, don't run it.

This should help:

Goto this Git and copy text
Save file as .REG file
Edit the file: remove unwanted lines ( leave only object you wish to hide )
Run the script

Godspeed
Edit:
Futureproofing, while keeping the link & credit. Hope this is acceptable?
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00



; delete keys for 3D Objects
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}]

; hide Documents Folder from Computer
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{f42ee2d3-909f-4907-8871-4c22fc0bf756}\PropertyBag]
"ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"

; hide Pictures Folder
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{0ddd015d-b06c-45d5-8c4c-f59713854639}\PropertyBag]
"ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"

; hide Videos Folder
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{35286a68-3c57-41a1-bbb1-0eae73d76c95}\PropertyBag]
"ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"

; hide Downloads Folder
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4}\PropertyBag]
"ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"

; hide Music Folder
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{a0c69a99-21c8-4671-8703-7934162fcf1d}\PropertyBag]
"ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"

; hide Desktop Folder
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}\PropertyBag]
"ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"


You should have included the reg data here in this question. If the link value changes or breaks your answer becomes invalid. Please fix this.
